# ¿Que estilo debo de dar para quitarle el link a mi menu?

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive

estoy hacinedo un menu ha,burgues en react pero las opciones del menu aparecen como links creo que hay una propiedad en css para que se vea asi sin link

Adjunto codigo css:

````
```@media all and (max-width:500px){

.Cabecera-button{
    display: flex;
}
.Cabecera-nav{
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height:0vh;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
.Cabecera-nav.isActive{
    height:50vh;
    opacity: 1;
}
.Cabecera-ul{
    flex-direction: column;
}
.Cabecera-li{
    margin: .5em 0;
    display: inline;
    font-size: larger;
}
````

}```

en que parte de mis clases tengo que ponerla para que desaparezcan los links?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si pones `text-decoration: none` no te aparecerá subrayado, si quieres que no te aparezca en azul, hay que modificar o añadir la propiedad `color` con el color que prefieras

Comment: listo si funciono gracias